# Deploy python app to existing azure app service with azure cli

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to deploy `python` app to an existing `azure` app service from `bitbucket` pipeline using azure cli, but I found only single way to deploy python app to azure app service ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=bash&pivots=python-framework-flask#deploy-the-sample))

```
az webapp up --name <app_name>
```

This seems not to work for already created azure app service. Also I found that it cannot be used for deployment in to the existing apps in this [comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/16777)

Since I want to run it from bitbucket `local git` is not an option to me. I also don't want direct integration with bitbucket via deployment center because I want to trigger the deployment on demand from bitbucket.

For example you can easily deploy `.net` app with zip deployment by running the following:

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group <resource_group> --name <app_name> --src <zip_name>
```

Can you do something similar for `python`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below script creates a new web app and deploys the python flask example from the docs you sent. It uses `az webapp deployment source config-zip` as you wanted. The part of the configuration worth exploring is the setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#enable-build-automation-for-zip-deploy). When set to true there are [additional steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python) running during deployment e.g. installing python packages.

```
    az group create -n <some_name> --location westus
    az appservice plan create --name <some_name> -g <some_name> --sku s1 --location westus --is-linux
    az webapp create -g <some_name> -n <some_globaly_unique_name> --plan <some_name> --runtime "PYTHON|3.7"
    az webapp config appsettings set -g <some_name> -n <some_globaly_unique_name> --settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1"
    az webapp config appsettings set -g <some_name> -n <some_globaly_unique_name> --settings SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true
    az webapp restart -n <some_globaly_unique_name> -g <some_name>

    git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/python-docs-hello-world
    cd .\python-docs-hello-world\
    Compress-Archive -Path * -DestinationPath package.zip
    az webapp deployment source config-zip -n <some_globaly_unique_name> -g <some_name> --src .\package.zip
```

Note that I used `Compress-Archive`, if you're not using Powershell, then you'll need to create a zip package different way.

Comment: My problem was that I was missing `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true`. After adding that it works fine, thanks! only thing I noticed is that it works without setting the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1"` flag.